# "Undeclared identifier" error if trying to include libvlc under Windows in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, libvlc

I Include the file "libvlc.h" from the VLC main git repository (https://github.com/videolan/vlc.git) in my Visual Studio project, I get various error e.g.

> The identifier "libvlc_int_t"" is not declared.   Video   [...]\vlc\src\libvlc.h  34

What am I doing wrong?

This is my (german) VS output:

```
 error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(34): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(35): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(35): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "," (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(41): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(41): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "," (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(45): error C2065: "vlc_object_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(45): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "," (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(49): error C2065: "vlc_object_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(49): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(56): error C2065: "vlc_thread_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(56): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "," (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(58): error C2065: "vlc_thread_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(58): error C2062: "int"-Typ unerwartet (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(60): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(60): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(76): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(76): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(77): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(77): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(78): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(78): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(85): error C3646: "lock": Unbekannter Überschreibungsspezifizierer (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(85): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt. (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(111): error C2065: "vlc_object_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(111): error C2065: "p_this": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(111): error C2275: "size_t": Ungültige Verwendung dieses Typs als Ausdruck (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
1>  c:\users\klang\work\projekte\video\video\builds\visualstudio2015\predefined c++ types (compiler internal)(16): note: Siehe Deklaration von "size_t" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(111): error C2146: Syntaxfehler: Fehlendes ")" vor Bezeichner "i_size" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(118): error C2065: "vlc_object_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(118): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "," (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(141): error C3646: "public_data": Unbekannter Überschreibungsspezifizierer (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(141): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt. (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(148): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ";" vor "*" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(148): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt. (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(148): error C2238: Unerwartete(s) Token vor ";" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(159): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(159): error C2065: "libvlc": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(159): error C2433: "libvlc_priv": "inline" bei der Deklaration von Daten nicht zulässig (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(160): error C2448: "libvlc_priv": Funktionsstil-Initialisierung scheint eine Funktionsdefinition zu sein (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(164): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(164): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "," (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(166): error C2065: "libvlc_int_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(166): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(187): error C3646: "date": Unbekannter Überschreibungsspezifizierer (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(187): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt. (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(196): error C3646: "last_update": Unbekannter Überschreibungsspezifizierer (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(196): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt. (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(226): error C2065: "input_thread_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(226): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: "," (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(227): error C2065: "input_stats_t": nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
(227): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: ")" (Quelldatei wird kompiliert ..\..\Source\Main.cpp)
```

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong, is not showing more information (e.g more errors you get).

Comment: `libvlc.h` is an internal header file in the library. Why are you including it?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a beginner in libVLC / C++. This was my first try to start. In my imagination I include the main header file and can use libVLC. Perhaps somebody can give me some start help..

Comment: Here's the tutorial: https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/

Comment: Here are instructions for Visual C++: https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Visual_C/

Comment: Yes I saw that before. But the first think that doesn't fit is: there is no "#include <vlc/vlc.h>"

Comment: You mean you don't have that file?

Comment: The file is not in the source repository.. When I do a git clone https://github.com/videolan/vlc.git. Thats why I tried to include the libvlc.h

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106458/discussion-between-christoph-and-martin-broadhurst).

Comment: "_Thats why I tried to include the libvlc.h_" that is an X-Y problem.  Ask about the problem, not the problem with your solution attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same in Visual Studio 2010 Update 1. However, it was easily fixed
replacing all the occurrences of "ssize_t" by "intptr_t".
Original comment by felipe.a...@gmail.com on 8 Feb 2013 at 1:22

It works.

Answer (score 0):

define ssize_t to SSIZE_T in predefined headers (ex:"stdafx.h") in Visual studio  .

Answer (score 0):

As above answers, you have to replace entire **ssize_t** with **intptr_t**.
If you use Visual Studio, you can try the following:

Project > Properties (Alt + F7) > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor
[image]
then edit Preprocessor Definitions to add this line: **ssize_t=intptr_t**
[image]

Or if you use CMakeLists.txt,
add this line to your CMakelists.txt:

```
target_compile_definitions(your-project PRIVATE -Dssize_t=intptr_t)
```

(Or if you use makefile.am, do the similar)